# My geth node is stuck on "looking for peers"

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-debugging

I start the geth node with these parameters, "`geth --ropsten --syncmode "light" --allow-insecure-unlock  --http --http.api "eth,net,web3,personal" --http.addr '0.0.0.0'` " but sometimes the block sync starts sometimes it gets stuck on "looking for peers". What could be the reason for this?

[image: image2][image: image1]

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you find any solution ?

Comment: I couldn't find a solution for linux and switched to windows now there is no problem for windows